# trace ftp file data in wireshark

Tags: ftp, tcp, wireshark

I am trying to analyze ftp traffic in Wireshark. I can see commands like Request: List, PORT.
But after FTP

`Response 150: Opening data channel for directory list.`

what I see immediately is

```
Response 226: Transfer OK
```

where is a list of files? Why I don't see it? (I've got this list - I can see it in terminal)

Answer (score 2):

You're following a single TCP connection. FTP data transfers occur over a second connection. Stop following the connection (or filtering) and you should see the data transfer, assuming you didn't use capture filters and actually captured it.

Comment: I tried this way but cannot find it. What filters might help? I tried by port 21 and second port of connection

Comment: As I already said, you'll miss it if you filter by port 21. Try not filtering at all, or filtering by IP address.

Comment: I ve found, forget that data comes from port 20. One question: this stream comes to also different port on ftp client but I cannot find where client passed this info to FTP server. Is this that number passed with Port request?

Comment: It sounds like you need to go read how the protocol works.

Comment: It might be more complicated in this case because it goes from my machine through TP-Link to my server and back. In FTP-Data frame I see  TP-Link as source, not server which is behind TP-Link

Comment: That's right, because the frame (layer 2) comes from your router (TP-Link).

Answer (score 0):

In wireshark, use the display filters as -

> ftp || ftp-data

This should allow you to see both, the file listing and the commands.
Make sure you don't have any capture filters.