# Tracing Active FTP Session (data channel)

Tags: ftp, tcpdump

To debug an issue with active FTP, we are tracing active FTP session traffic with tcpdump running in a toolbox container on a GKE node. The active FTP session is failing on the data channel.

I am familiar with the differences between active mode and passive mode FTP (our platform has to support both and we use passive mode whenever possible).

To debug the failing active FTP data channel, we are tracing successful active FTP sessions to clarify on the flow in our environment with our FTP server implementation. The issue here is:

**Capturing packets from the data channel in a successful active FTP session**

Had a look at [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/521458/trace-ftp-file-data-in-wireshark) and while similar, it doesn't seem resolved and our situation may be different. The trace is run with:

```
tcpdump -vnn -w 002.pcap -i eth0
```

The pcap file is then opened in Wireshark. Filtering on the FTP protocol shows the control channel portion of the session with clarity. The FTP client/server communications are all as expected between the client's ephemeral port and the server port 21. This flow includes the expected commands for authentication, setting up TYPE I, a CWD to the correct folder, SIZE, PORT, and RETR for the filename.

The PORT command looks fine, including the client IP and port for the server to use in the subsequent data channel portion of the session (to download one file). E.g.:

```
PORT 1,2,3,4,51,105
```

which converts: ( 51x256+105 ) to port 13161.

However, in Wireshark, after:

```
client:27154 > server:21 RETR <filename>
server:21    > client:27154 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
```

the only additional packets captured are:

```
server:21    > client:27154 226 Transfer complete.
client:27154 > server:21 6 QUIT
server:21    > client:27154 221 Goodbye.
```

Our FTP server implementation does not use port 20 for the data channel, it uses a random available port. In any event, we expected to see the server establish the data channel like so:

```
server:<random port> > client:13161
```

And an additional line or two showing the actual transfer.

- Is the tcpdump filtering itself the issue?
- Something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Are there multiple interfaces or bonds and could there be a routing difference where outgoing traffic to the client IP-address is routed over a different interface and simply not present in the capture made on eth0?

Comment: That's a great idea - thanks @HBruijn - the answer is I'm not sure. I captured on eth0 as you can see. There is an interface on the node that is specific to the pod (running on it) that runs the app with the embedded FTP server. I will add that interface to the trace or possibly just use `-i any` and follow-up

Comment: Follow-up: 

I used `-i any` with the `tcpdump` trace and checked in Wireshark, but still cannot find the data channel packets. The server-side application is clustered and I checked traces from all instances (on the off chance that the data channel was being initiated from a different node/pod than the one that started the control channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was error on my part. After checking [RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and its description of the data channel for TYPE I (image/binary), and adjusting the view in Wireshark to simply trace in sequence (by time); the TCP packets for the data channel are in fact there.

For anyone who runs into this, with active FTP, in the **control channel**:

Given a response to REQUEST SIZE like this:

```
FTP ... Response: 213 3981
```

which indicates a file size of 3981 bytes, and a PORT command like this:

```
FTP ... Request: PORT 1,2,3,4,51,105
```

which indicates the IP and port for the server to use when establishing the TCP connection with the client for the start of the data channel.

*To convert the 5th and 6th octet to the port number:*
*51x256+105 = 13161*

Wireshark should display the **data channel** packets like this:

```
No. | Time      | Source    | Destination   | Protocol   | Length   | Info
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
89  | 6.982066  | 10.5.4.3  | 1.2.3.4       | TCP        | 76       | 33841 → 13161 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=28400 Len=0 MSS=1420 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3979605739 TSecr=0 WS=128
93  | 7.390712  | 1.2.3.4   | 10.5.4.3      | TCP        | 64       | 13161 → 33841 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1360 SACK_PERM=1
98  | 7.390818  | 10.5.4.3  | 1.2.3.4       | TCP        | 56       | 33841 → 13161 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=28400 Len=0
101 | 7.395054  | 10.5.4.3  | 1.2.3.4       | TCP        | 2776     | 33841 → 13161 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=28400 Len=2720
104 | 7.395068  | 10.5.4.3  | 1.2.3.4       | TCP        | 1317     | 33841 → 13161 [PSH, ACK] Seq=2721 Ack=1 Win=28400 Len=1261
107 | 7.395096  | 10.5.4.3  | 1.2.3.4       | TCP        | 56       | 33841 → 13161 [FIN, ACK] Seq=3982 Ack=1 Win=28400 Len=0
```

The TCP packets above show the 3-way TCP handshake: SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK and then the actual binary transfer. You can sum the payload lengths (in the Info column) from packets 101 and 104  to get the file size confirmed earlier in the control channel.

```
Len=2720 + Len=1261 = 3981
```

Then you should see the final FTP 226 confirmation in the **control channel**:

```
FTP ... Response: 226 Transfer complete.
```